# How can I prevent URLDownloadToFile from retrieving from the cache?

Tags: c++, winapi, wininet

I am using URLDownloadToFile to retrieve a file from a website. Subsequent calls return the original file rather than an updated version.  I assume it is retrieving a cached version.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Call DeleteUrlCacheEntry with the same URL just prior to calling URLDownloadToFile.
You will need to link against Wininet.lib

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it is pulling a cached version of the file by default.  To avoid the cache file completely, pass an IBindStatusCallback object in the lpfnCB
parameter of URLDownloadToFile().  In your implemented IBindStatusCallback::GetBindInfo() method, include the BINDF_GETNEWESTVERSION flag, and optionally also the BINDF_NOWRITECACHE flag, in the value you return via the grfBINDF parameter.  If you want the cache file, if present, to be updated instead of skippe, specify the BINDF_RESYNCHRONIZE flag instead.

Comment: Could you show an example? I checked the pointer and or'd in the values like this and it still used the cached value: *grfBINDF |= BINDF_GETNEWESTVERSION | BINDF_NOWRITECACHE;

Comment: I don't have an example to provide. What I said is documented behavior on MSDN. Try replacing `|=` with `=`, eg: `*grfBINDF = BINDF_GETNEWESTVERSION | BINDF_NOWRITECACHE;` As you have it, you are preserving existing bits, so if the variable is uninitialized on the caller's end then the result may end up with random bits you don't want, like `BINDF_OFFLINEOPERATION` or `BINDF_GETFROMCACHE_IF_NET_FAIL`. Always zero out output flags before assigning their bits.

Comment: Has anyone actually verified that you can stop the cache with bind flags? BINDF_NOWRITECACHE needs BINDF_PULLDATA and that needs BINDF_ASYNCHRONOUS. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27518724/urldownloadtofile-writes-objects-in-the-cache-when-run-as-a-service#comment43467667_27518724 says it is not possible and I believe that person was on the IE team.

Answer (score 3):

Could you add a harmless query parameter to the end of your URL?

https://stackoverflow.com/?CacheBuster=1020am

Answer (score 2):

clean cache

```
// Limpa cache do Internet Explorer
procedure DeletaIECache;
var
     lpEntryInfo: PInternetCacheEntryInfo;
     hCacheDir: LongWord;
     dwEntrySize: LongWord;
begin
     dwEntrySize := 0;
     FindFirstUrlCacheEntry(nil, TInternetCacheEntryInfo(nil^), dwEntrySize) ;
     GetMem(lpEntryInfo, dwEntrySize) ;
     if dwEntrySize > 0 then lpEntryInfo^.dwStructSize := dwEntrySize;
     hCacheDir := FindFirstUrlCacheEntry(nil, lpEntryInfo^, dwEntrySize) ;
     if hCacheDir <> 0 then
     begin
         repeat
         DeleteUrlCacheEntry(lpEntryInfo^.lpszSourceUrlName) ;
         FreeMem(lpEntryInfo, dwEntrySize) ;
         dwEntrySize := 0;
         FindNextUrlCacheEntry(hCacheDir, TInternetCacheEntryInfo(nil^), dwEntrySize) ;
         GetMem(lpEntryInfo, dwEntrySize) ;
         if dwEntrySize > 0 then lpEntryInfo^.dwStructSize := dwEntrySize;
         until not FindNextUrlCacheEntry(hCacheDir, lpEntryInfo^, dwEntrySize) ;
     end;
     FreeMem(lpEntryInfo, dwEntrySize) ;
     FindCloseUrlCache(hCacheDir) ;
end;
```