# URLDownloadToFile() writes objects in the cache when run as a service

Tags: c++, caching, wininet

I have a piece of software that downloads images into a working directory and then processes them to create a video; afterwards, those files are removed by an independent script.

The problem is that it also writes files into the following directory (the software runs as a system service):

```
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files\Content.IE5
```

To make things worse, there doesn't seem to be a limit to how many files are kept there; this causes server issues due to the hard disc shortage.

In an attempt to prevent files from being cached we have tried the following:

1. Use `Pragma:` and `Cache-Control:` headers on the server to prevent caching on the client;
2. Use `DeleteUrlCacheEntry()` to remove the cache entry after download has completed; returns `ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`;
3. Use `IBindStatusCallback::GetBindInfo()` and set the passed `grfBINDF` to `BINDF_NOWRITECACHE|BINDF_PRAGMA_NO_CACHE|BINDF_GETNEWESTVERSION`.

Unfortunately, the aforementioned approaches don't prevent cache files from still being written into the internet cache.

Is there something I've missed?

Comment: [WinInet is not recommended](https://support.microsoft.com/KB/238425) for use in services; UrlMon even less so. Consider switching to [WinHTTP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384273.aspx) - it was specifically designed to be used from a service. WinHTTP doesn't automatically cache.

Comment: That may be something I could consider, though it will take an effort to switch over; strangely, this behaviour seems to be different across our platforms =/

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Btw, the first and third option were tested using a regular user account.

Comment: I do not know how to make `UrlDownloadToFile` to not cache. I do know that WinHTTP doesn't cache even if you wanted it to.

Comment: Can you show the code which calls `DeleteUrlCacheEntry()` as this works for me in what appears to be a similar scenario?

Comment: @user1793036 Yeah, it works for me too *if* it's not run as a service.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik can you tell if WinInet is not recommended to run as a service, what about Internet Explorer (which is relied on WinInet)? what about web browser control based applications?

Comment: @Guy These applications are not services, and it is not recommended to run them from a service. I suppose I may not quite understand the question; I don't see what you are driving at.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I meant not running them from a service. Like using psexec tool with session 0 flag. So, the answer is yes, if I'm getting you right. It is not recomanded to execute ie or web browser control applications from a service (session 0).

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I read ms kb on that (wininet not supported to run from a service) but couldn't understand the concrete implications when doing so. Would appreciate some clarifications on that if possible.

Comment: @Guy I don't have any additional insights beyond what's in the article.