# URLDownloadToFile is not working properly

Tags: vba, excel

URLDownloadToFile is automatically downloading files to cache instead of specific path

**Example:**

URLDownloadToFile is downloading files to cache path `C:\Users\38100442\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\INetCache\IE\KUQPK734` instead of specific path `D:\example\filename.pdf`. I want all the files to be downloaded in `D:\example\filename.pdf`.

Please see the below code

```
Private Declare Function URLDownloadToFile Lib "urlmon" _
                         Alias "URLDownloadToFileA" ( _
                         ByVal pCaller As Long, _
                         ByVal szURL As String, _
                         ByVal szFileName As String, _
                         ByVal dwReserved As Long, _
                         ByVal lpfnCB As Long _
                         ) As Long

Public IE As Object

Sub workflow()

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Macro")
    lstrw = wb.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    strDest = Sheets("Macro").TextBox1.Text
    If Trim(LCase(strDest)) = "false" Or Trim(strDest) = "" Then
        MsgBox "Please select the Output Folder", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Set IE = New InternetExplorerMedium

    IE.Visible = True
    Application.wait (Now + #12:00:03 AM#)
    IE.navigate "http://172.20.41.73:7003/taskspace/component/main/?appname=coe"

    wait
    'While IE.document.ReadyState <> "complete": DoEvents: Wend
IE.document.getElementById("LoginUsername").Value = "38100562"
IE.document.getElementById("LoginPassword").Value = "!Redsba05%"
IE.document.getElementsByName("ImgMgrLogin_loginButton_0")(0).Click
wait
Set ieAnchors = IE.document.getElementsByName("RoleSelector_rolesList_0")(0)

For Each Anchor In ieAnchors
    DoEvents
    If Anchor.innerHTML = "finance_role" Then
        Anchor.Selected = True
        IE.document.getElementsByName("RoleSelector_rolesSubmitButton_0")(0).Click
        Exit For
    End If
Next Anchor
wait
i0 = 0
i1 = 1

wait
wait
For i = 2 To lstrw
    DoEvents
    If Trim(LCase(Range("b" & i).Value)) = "" Then
        casID_val = Trim(wb.Range("A" & i).Value)
upline:
        On Error Resume Next
upline2:
        'While IE.document.frames.Item(2).document.ReadyState <> "complete": DoEvents: Wend
    Set ieAnchors = IE.document.frames.Item(2).document.getElementsByTagName("a")
    If ieAnchors Is Nothing Then GoTo upline
    For Each Anchor In ieAnchors
        DoEvents
        If Anchor.Name = "NavigationbarComponent_NavigationbarComponent_tabsImgMgrNav_FinanceSearch_close_0" Then
            Anchor.Click
        End If
    Next Anchor
    wait
    'While IE.document.frames.Item(3).document.frames.Item(1).document.ReadyState <> "complete": DoEvents: Wend

Set caseID = Nothing
Set caseID = IE.document.frames.Item(3).document.frames.Item(1).document.getElementById("body_body_body_xform1_object_name_0_value_0_0")
If caseID Is Nothing Then GoTo upline2


caseID.Value = casID_val
IE.document.frames.Item(3).document.frames.Item(1).document.getElementsByName("body_body_body_xform1_search_trigger_0_value_0_0")(0).Click
wait
'While IE.document.frames.Item(3).document.frames.Item(1).document.ReadyState <> "complete": DoEvents: Wend

Set openItem = IE.document.frames.Item(3).document.frames.Item(1).document.getElementsByTagName("tr")
If Trim(openItem(40).innerText) <> "No items" Then
openItem(40).FireEvent "ondblclick", 1, 2
wait
'While IE.document.frames.Item(3).document.frames.Item(1).document.frames.document.frames.Item(1).document.ReadyState <> "complete": DoEvents: Wend
dataGrid_id = ""
Set data_item = IE.document.frames.Item(3).document.frames.Item(1).document.frames.document.frames.Item(1).document.getElementById("FolderContentViewComponent___XFORMS_FOLDERCONTENT_DATAGRID_CONTROL_NAME_0_data")
For Each data_item_innertext In data_item.getElementsByTagName("tr")
DoEvents
If InStr(LCase(data_item_innertext.innerText), "pdf") > 0 Then
    dataGrid_id = data_item_innertext.ID
    Exit For
End If
Next
If dataGrid_id = "" Then
wb.Range("b" & i).Value = "Not Download"
Set close_tab = IE.document.frames.Item(2).document.getElementById("tab_NavigationbarComponent_openItemTab_" & i0 & "_0").getElementsByTagName("a")
For Each cls In close_tab
    DoEvents
    cls.FireEvent "onclick"
Next cls
wait
'While IE.document.frames.Item(3).document.frames.Item(1).document.frames.document.frames.Item(1).document.ReadyState <> "complete": DoEvents: Wend
i0 = i0 + 1
i1 = i1 + 1
GoTo nxt_loop
End If
Set pdf_pth = IE.document.frames.Item(3).document.frames.Item(1).document.frames.document.frames.Item(1).document.getElementById(dataGrid_id)
pdf_pth.FireEvent "ondblclick", 1, 2
wait
'While IE.document.frames.Item(3).document.frames.Item(1).document.ReadyState <> "complete": DoEvents: Wend
pdf_path_URL = ""
Set pdfIframe = IE.document.frames.Item(3).document.frames.Item(1).document.getElementsByTagName("iFrame")
For Each pdf_scr In pdfIframe
DoEvents
If pdf_scr.Name = "docview_contents_docview_contents_docview_contents_xform1_ImageViewer_0_value_0_0" Then
pdf_path_URL = pdf_scr.src
Exit For
End If
Next pdf_scr
pdf_filename = ""
pdf_filename = Trim(IE.document.frames.Item(2).document.getElementById("tab_NavigationbarComponent_openItemTab_" & i1 & "_0").innerText)

URLDownloadToFile 0, pdf_path_URL, strDest & casID_val & "_" & pdf_filename, 0, 0
Set close_tab = IE.document.frames.Item(2).document.getElementById("tab_NavigationbarComponent_openItemTab_" & i1 & "_0").getElementsByTagName("a")
For Each cls In close_tab
DoEvents
cls.FireEvent "onclick"
Next cls
wait
'While IE.document.frames.Item(2).document.ReadyState <> "complete": DoEvents: Wend
Set close_tab = IE.document.frames.Item(2).document.getElementById("tab_NavigationbarComponent_openItemTab_" & i0 & "_0").getElementsByTagName("a")
For Each cls In close_tab
DoEvents
cls.FireEvent "onclick"
Next cls
wait
i0 = i0 + 2
i1 = i1 + 2
wb.Range("b" & i).Value = "Download"
wb.Range("c" & i).Value = casID_val & "_" & pdf_filename
Else
wb.Range("b" & i).Value = "No Items"
End If
nxt_loop:
ThisWorkbook.Save
End If

Next i
IE.Quit
Set IE = Nothing
MsgBox "Process Complete", vbInformation

End Sub

Function wait()
    Application.wait (Now + #12:00:03 AM#)
    While IE.Busy
        DoEvents
    Wend
    While IE.document.ReadyState <> "complete": DoEvents: Wend
End Function
```

Comment: Please see [MCVE]. Is all this code really  necessary to demonstrate the problem at hand? Including only the relevant code will make answering this more appealing.

Comment: Also, the fact that the above  (workflow sub)  still hasn't indented properly indicates something is off in the actual code. Maybe something is not closed properly or something else. Missing variable declarations also means you are not using Option Explicit at the top of your code - which you should.  And get rid of that On Error Resume Next which is hiding any errors. And should your wait be Application.Wait with times specified?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27518724/urldownloadtofile-writes-objects-in-the-cache-when-run-as-a-service

Comment: @ThanisAlbert Please add a `Debug.Print strDest & casID_val & "_" & pdf_filename` directly before you call `URLDownloadToFile` and tell us the output of your intermediate window. Also make sure that this path already exists (this is required!).

Comment: @Pᴇʜ The OP did ask two identical questions - it appears one of these has since been deleted as it's no longer listed under his profile.

Comment: Dear all, I have made mistake at download URL link, I have corrected it. Now it is downloading to exact path.

Comment: Well, we could close/delete this question then. I think there is no useful information for future readers.